# Check how string is encoded (UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8821,

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to analyze the correctness of the text I receive in .txt files for processing.
It is always string with different length and it is coded for example in ASCII, ISO-8821,
ISO-8859-1, UTF-8 and more I don't know. In first step I have to recognize how this text
(string) is encoded or whether it is encoded in a specific way, e.g. ISO-8821.
I can't find the way to do it - javascript, typescript, etc. How can I check it?

Comment: You may be interested in the npm package [jschardet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jschardet) which does this kind of thing out of the box.

Comment: Does this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file#:~:text=Files%20generally%20indicate%20their%20encoding,a%20UTF%2D8%20encoded%20file. help?

Comment: Unfortunately jschardet has no 8821 and generally speking it's hard to find some kind of such a procedures. Tnanks for answers.